# Wordpress - NGINX CONF ERRORS

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-config

My conf;

```
server {

listen 80;

listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/html/wpress; index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name wpress.conf www.wpress.conf;

error_log /var/log/nginx/wpress.conf_error.log;

access_log /var/log/nginx/wpress.conf_access.log;

client_max_body_size 100M;

location / {

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

}

location ~ \.php$ {

include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

}

}
```

Ill try add
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
{
return 405;s
}

But it always end up with "unexpected }" fml.

Tried many ways to import it.

Can someone just explain how to add things like this to server block succesfully, ty!

Comment: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/wpress.conf:25

Comment: You have an `s` after the `return 405;`